# YoutubeExtratctor Android dependency Error

Tags: android

I have an error in this dependency

`implementation 'com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:v1.7.0'`

and the error is

`ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:v1.7.0`

I'm trying  to use it to fetch an url of youtube video so that I can use it in Exoplayer

Answer (score 2):

Do you have already the jitpack.io added to your repositories config in the  `build.gradle` file?

Something like

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } // this is the line that you probably need
    }
}
```

The idea is that gradle needs to know where to find artifacts build from github, this is usually from jitpack.io. By default, this line is not generated in the `build.gradle` file so you must add it manually.

Hope it helps

Comment: Sure, does this fix your problem ?